# How do I connect to MySQL instance on Google SQL using google console?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform

I have been following tutorials on how to create an instance of MySQL and connecting to it via the google console. I am getting a **ERROR: (gcloud.beta.sql.connect) Failed to start the Cloud SQL Proxy** when entering this command: `gcloud beta sql connect cloud-sql-demo --user=root`

I have my instance running and here is the full error message:

```
Starting Cloud SQL Proxy: [/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/bin/cloud_sql_proxy -instances learninggcp-281321:us-central1:cloud-sql-demo=tcp:9470 -credential_file /tmp/tmp.wDzxY0bzV6/legacy_credentials/qwthompson1@g
mail.com/adc.json]]
2020/06/24 16:57:54 Rlimits for file descriptors set to {&{8500 1048576}}
2020/06/24 16:57:54 invalid json file "/tmp/tmp.wDzxY0bzV6/legacy_credentials/qwthompson1@gmail.com/adc.json": open /tmp/tmp.wDzxY0bzV6/legacy_credentials/qwthompson1@gmail.com/adc.json: no such file or direc
tory
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.sql.connect) Failed to start the Cloud SQL Proxy.
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like there's credential issues maybe. Are you logged into the right project/configuration via `gcloud init`?

Something else you could try, if you have a service account key file locally, is set the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to the path to your service account key file. e.g. `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/service/account/file.json`. Making sure that the service account has the proper permissions to connect to the Cloud SQL instance.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue. Turns out you need to login again, as the credentials file is missing right after the login.

Run: `gcloud auth application-default login` to login and get Application Default Credentials (ADC).

The command will state that the login is not required. Do it anyway :)

Running `gcloud beta sql connect ...` afterwards worked for me and prompted for the user's password.

More information at https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc